# How to disable a button after clicking a button using vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am making a voting application. I want to disable the button once clicking the voting button. How to disable the button.

template

```
  <v-btn
   v-for="choice in data.choices"
   @click="doVote(choice.id)"
   color="success"
   v-bind:key="choice.id">
   votes: {{ choice.votes }}
  </v-btn>
```

script

```
  data () {
    return {
      vote: null,
      questions: [],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    fetchData () {
      this.$request.questions.list().then(res => {
        this.questions = res.data.results
      })
    },

    // add votes
    doVote (vote) {
      if (!vote) {
        return
      }
      this.$request.questions.vote(vote).then(res => {
        this.fetchData()
      })
    },

  mounted () {
    this.fetchData()
  },
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`v-btn`has a [`disabled` property](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons) you can use; One way to do this could be create a `clicked` field to record all buttons you've clicked and check whether a specific button is in the clicked array:

```
<v-btn
   :disabled="clicked.includes(choice.id)"
   v-for="choice in data.choices"
   @click="doVote(choice.id)"
   color="success"
   v-bind:key="choice.id">
   votes: {{ choice.votes }}
</v-btn>
```

In `data`, initialize `clicked` as an empty array:

```
data () {
    return {
      vote: null,
      questions: [],
      clicked: []
    }
  }
```

Then in the `doVote` method, push the `choice.id` to `clicked` array when the event is fired:

```
doVote (vote) {
  this.clicked.push(vote)
  if (!vote) {
    return
  }
  this.$request.questions.vote(vote).then(res => {
    this.fetchData()
  })
}
```

Comment: i don't think this will work , it will disable all the buttons , thought , as i  see from his  code there is an iterator on choices, i think it will be better if he add status isDisabled to the response choices from his API ?

Comment: @TahaAzzabi Yeah. You're right. I missed the `for` loop completely :-

Answer (score 13):

The simplest thing do is set a variable when the voting button is pressed and then bind it to the buttons 'disabled' property:

```
v-bind:disabled="hasVoted"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an another variable (in this case `votes`) which will record the votes and then you can use it to determine if the button should be disabled (see `votes.indexOf(choice.id) !== -1`).

template:

```
  <v-btn
   :disabled="votes.indexOf(choice.id) !== -1"
   v-for="choice in data.choices"
   @click="doVote(choice.id)"
   color="success"
   v-bind:key="choice.id">
   votes: {{ choice.votes }}
  </v-btn>
```

script

```
  data () {
    return {
      votes: [],
      vote: null,
      questions: [],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    fetchData () {
      this.$request.questions.list().then(res => {
        this.questions = res.data.results
      })
    },

    // add votes
    doVote (vote) {
      if (!vote) {
        return
      }
      this.$request.questions.vote(vote).then(res => {
        this.fetchData()
        this.votes.push(vote);
      })
    },

  mounted () {
    this.fetchData()
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon the same issue and I thought I'd share how I solved my problem which again will include creating another array to record your clicks like mentioned in the previous answers and then using [Array.prototype.some() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to determine which buttons to disable by binding the disabled prop of your v-btn component like so:

```
<template>
  <v-btn
   :disabled="votes.some(vote => vote.id === choice.id)"
   v-for="choice in data.choices"
   @click="doVote(choice.id)"
   color="success"
   v-bind:key="choice.id">
   votes: {{ choice.votes }}
  </v-btn>
</template>
```

I have to reference Michael's answer on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript) which is where I found my solution